# Tring to automate sampling of DC current using SCPI commands, having issues with setup

Tags: c#, automated-tests

Im trying to automate the sampling of a current profile for a PCB using the keysight 34465A DMM and a Rigol 811 power supply. Having issues with the timing and setup of my test code, particularly the running of the sample interval after I power the power supply. My aim is to pull the standard deviation, average , and array of samples to plot to excel.

using scpi, my setup is :
-configure range ( 3amps in this case)
-set measurement type (Volts or current)
-set integration mode (NLPC or APER)
-Set sample count, source, and sample interval (would like to know how to set up duration of sampling)
-Enable stats calculations
-Start Reading
-Power up board to capture initial peak current
-wait for processes to end 
-read Standard deviation, average and values

```
CONF:CURR:DC 3
CURR:DC:NPLC .002
SAMP:COUN 15000
SAMP:SOUR:TIM
SAMP:TIM MIN
CALC:AVER:STAT ON
INIT
*turn rigol power supply on*
*WAI 
 CALC:AVER:AVER?
 CALC:AVER:SDEV?
 FETCH?

 public string CurrentProfile(string measurementType, string 
 integrationMode, string integrationTime, string count, string source, 
 string timer, string range)
    {   
        string avg;
        string stdDev;
        string values;

        SendMessage("CONF:CURR:DC 3");
        //NPLC integration times are as follows : .001, .002, .006, .02, 
         .06, .2, 1, 10, 100
        //Aperture intehration times are as follows : 20E-6, 40E-6, 100E- 
        6, .3E-3, 1E-3, 3E-3, 16.7E-3, .167, 1.67
        SetIntegrationTimeMode(measurementType, integrationMode, 
        integrationTime);

        SetSample(count, source, timer);
        SendMessage("CALC:AVER:STAT ON");
        SendMessage("INIT");
        RigolDP811A powerOut = new RigolDP811A();
        powerOut.Setoutputstatus("ON");
        SendMessage("*WAI");
        avg = SendAndReadMessage("CALC:AVER:AVER?");
        stdDev = SendAndReadMessage("CALC:AVER:SDEV?");
        values = SendAndReadMessage("FETCH?");
    }
```

I expected for the 34465A to start running an collecting data but I am simply getting an error message